# .one is not working properly on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to execute my javascript function once and I am using this code

```
$('.hov').one('mouseenter', function() {
alert('You will only see this once.');
imageSliderNews.reload();
});
```

but strangely it is not working properly.If I change .one to .live, then it executes correctly but I need it to execute only once. Can anyone explain why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe try using a recent jQuery? `.live` was deprecated and removed some time ago.

Comment: Can u tell me the latest version?

Comment: `2.1.4` unless you need legacy browser support, in which case `1.11.3`. [Both are available on the jQuery website](https://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: Are you calling this inside $(document).ready() ?

Comment: `it is not working properly` is vague. What make you say it's not working as it should? What do you observe, what do you expect

Comment: @Deftwun oh okay ill try

Comment: @Deftwun Thats it thank you , I forgot to do that :) sorry im a complete newbie

Answer (score 2):

Try calling this inside of [$(document).ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

It's possible that your elements don't yet exist in the DOM by the time you attach your handler.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the code before there's an element with class "hov" in the DOM. Move your `.one()` call to a place where you know the element exists.